# Adusting image margin in footer

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here in the footer I have kept one image. But I could not adjust it's top and bottom margin.

Image should be in exactly middle of the footer. Which class reflect it?

CODEPEN DEMO: [Demo](http://codepen.io/karimkhan/pen/qcLiF)

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">     
                  <li><a href="#" class="navbar-brand scroll-top"><img class="img-brand" src="http://shayariwallpapers.files.wordpress.com/2013/03/sher-shayari.jpg" height="25" width="20"></img></a></li> 
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">What is facebook?</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about">How does it work?</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact">Feedback</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact">Contact us</a></li>                            
                </ul>
            </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
```

I want to adjust share-shayri.jpg image in middle of the footer.

**UPDATE**

Note: in header also I have one image. I dont want changing the stlye into footer to be affected in header.

Comment: Just to clarify is vertical align?

Answer (score 2):

You could wrap the image inside a set of two divs:

```
<li>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div align="center" id="wrapper-inner">
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand scroll-top">
                <img class="img-brand" src="http://shayariwallpapers.files.wordpress.com/2013/03/sher-shayari.jpg" height="25" width="20"></img>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

And set the css:

```
#wrapper
{
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

#wrapper-inner
{
    display:table-cell;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

This should center it both horizontal and verticaly

Comment: hi...congrats on ur 1st 10 rep....**advice :** first try to find bugs of OP...then if you feel better solution exist..suggest with a reason!! :)

Comment: Thanks for the advice... appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

Your css is bit messed up to study...plus...reference link url are not answered, still :

Since, your image is inside `a` tag, its `overflow:hidden` set somewhere...identify it and then add this in your css

```
 a.my_custom_a{
      display:inline-block;
      border:1px solid red;
      vertical-align: middle; /*key*/
    }
```

for markup

```
  <a href="#" class="navbar-brand scroll-top my_custom_a">
     <img class="img-brand" src="http://shayariwallpapers.files.wordpress.com/2013/03/sher-shayari.jpg" height="25" width="20"></img>
  </a>
```

this would solve your problem!

Comment: you rocks, i hope you remember

Comment: But still it does not make it in middle

Comment: add this in your `a` tag containing the image => `border:1px solid #000;` and you will not see the bottom border...this mean that bottom is cut-off...your image is aligned vertically middle but due to `hidden overflow`, you are not able to see it....

Comment: it is not to align in the middle mate...it is to show you that image `container` is not fully visible....!!! :p

Comment: So can you plase help me to align it in middle

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44792/discussion-between-noobeditor-and-user3121782)